# Getting the first element in string/list

Tags: python

OK, I have file with this data:

```
data = """4,sons,hey,what,Z,U   
          3,dogs,watch,who,U,H
          2,times,did,1,won,G"""
```

I'm wondering, How can I extract the first element from this data?

In this case first place is number so I tried:

```
filter(str.isdigit, data)
```

but since I have other numbers in data its not working for me. Any new ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a csv file. Use the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module to parse it:

```
import csv
with open('file.csv') as f:
    csvreader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in csvreader: 
        print row[0]
```

or if you find you want all the columns:

```
import csv
with open('file.csv') as f:
    csvreader = csv.reader(f)
    for number, what, are, these, entries, called in csvreader:
        print number
```